# Objective-C Calendar Grid

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, calendar

I need to create calendar grid with dates. I have number of days in current month and have first weekday index in current month.
The dufficult for me is how to create calendar grid with buttons and move first weekday to weekday name.

Fox example:

```
Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat
             1    2  3   4
5   6   7    8    9  10   11
....
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet for displaying a calendar grid with buttons is to use a `UICollectionView`. If you search for "UICollectionView calendar" there are a few sample projects out there you could start from. For example [here](http://maniacdev.com/2013/04/ui-control-providing-an-infinite-scrolling-iphone-calendar-control-using-uicollectionview) and [here](https://github.com/monospacecollective/MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout).

Answer (score 2):

You can checkout the project from [DPCalendar](https://github.com/ethan-fang/DPCalendar)

It uses UICollectionView and draws events. it shows events and special days in a monthly view layout. And you can even check how the events are displayed inside the items of the collection view.